# Passing tensorflow-probability distributions as bijector parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to create a TransformedDistribution whose transforming bijector (a Chain of bijectors) has some of its components parametrized as distributions themselves, with the objective of having a different result everytime I transform some tensor through the bijector (because the parameters of the bijector will be sampled each time as well).

Let's take a very simple example to illustrate what I say (without Chains):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

base_distribution = tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=1.5)
x = base_distribution.sample(10) # Sample 10 times, to get fixed values
# Define the distribution for the parameter of the bijector
scale_distribution = tfd.Uniform(low=2/3-0.5, high=2/3+0.5)
# This is how I wish it was, but fails
bijector = tfb.Scale(scale=scale_distribution)
# ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'Uniform' has no len()
```

Elaborating on the example a bit more:

```py
transformed_dist = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    base_distribution,
    bijector)

transformed_dist.sample() # get one sample of the original distribution, 
                          # scaled with some scale factor drawn from the
                          # uniform distribution.
```

I know there is a way to build hierarchical distribution models with a JointDistribution, which lets me use one (or more) distributions as the parameters of another distribution then sample from the joint distribution.

But I have not found an equivalent way of randomly parametrize a bijector. An approach that "works" but is a bit cumbersome is:

```py
# Works, but the sample is generated and becomes fixed when defining the bijector
bijector = tfb.Scale(scale=tf.random.uniform(minval=2/3-0.5, maxval=2/3+0.5,))

transformed_dist = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    base_distribution,
    bijector)

transformed_dist.sample() # Now the distribution will always sample from
                          # a Normal what is Scaled by a deterministic 
                          # parameter, that was randomly generated at 
                          # definition time.
```

As I explain in the code this would require me to rerun the whole code block every time I want the parameter to be different.

The reason I want to do it like this is that I want to automatically generate samples in such a way that a certain rotation is randomized, i.e. get a different distribution every time I sample.

Note: I'm using tensorflow >2.1 with eager execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still think a JointDistribution is the way to go here, doing something like

```
joint = tfd.JointDistributionSequential([
   tfd.Uniform(...),
   lambda unif: tfb.MyBijector(param=unif)(tfd.Normal(0., 1.))
])
```

to feed into the bijector param.

However, you could also cobble something together with `tfp.util.DeferredTensor`. This is an object that can be used anywhere a Tensor can be, but whose value is taken from the execution of a given function. E.g.

```
rand_dt = tfp.util.DeferredTensor(
    pretransformed_input=1.,  # value doesn't matter here
    transform_fn=lambda _: tf.random.uniform(minval=1., maxval=2.)
)

td = tfb.Scale(scale=rand_dt)(tfd.Normal(0., 1.))

for i in range(5):
  print(td.sample())
  # will print a sample with a different random scale on each call
```

Here's a colab, with a slightly modified version of the above example, to illustrate what's happening: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1akjX6a1W-RJoUjsy0hVOrrRAQiBIYjY-

HTH!

UPDATE:

Upon further reflection, I should actually give some pretty strong caution around the second pattern. Unfortunately it's very hard to guarantee that a single Tensor-ified value of a DeferredTensor will be used consistently -- even in the context of, say, a single Distribution method invocation -- and so doing anything that has side effects can be dangerous. For example:

```
rand_dt = tfp.util.DeferredTensor(
    pretransformed_input=1.,  # value doesn't matter here
    transform_fn=lambda _: tf.random.uniform(minval=1., maxval=2.)
)

td = tfb.Scale(scale=rand_dt)(tfd.Normal(0., 1.))

sample = td.sample()  # sample from TD with some random scale
print(td.log_prob(sample))  # new scale; wrong log_prob!
```

One workaround would be to use the stateless TF sampling API, either directly or by passing list-valued or Tensor-valued seeds to TFP (see more on stateless sampling semantics [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/PRNGS.md)), and explicitly manage the seeds. This may make the above example much uglier and hard to work with though (you'd probably need to have a Variable floating around that acts as the seed input and gets `assign`ed each time you want a new sample)

Your best bet is probably to use the JointDistribution approach!

Comment: Thank you! I went with the JointDistribution solution in the end. I wish there was a way to define chained bijectors with placeholder parameters that can then be instantiated later (on `sample` call for example). That would let me to define the `Chain` outside the `Joint`, making the code less nested and more "encapsulated" (so to speak).

Comment: If you're willing to roll your own Bijectors, there is functionality in TransformedDistribution to plumb `bijector_kwargs` into the relevant bijector methods. This is used in some places like the `condition_kwargs` in `MaskedAutoregressiveFlow`, but can't be used for, say, the Scale bijector which demands its parameter be set up front. It could be interesting to allow a sort of lazy parameter, which if unspecified must be given at method invocation time. I expect there'd be a lot of subtleties involved, but might be possible (someday) :)

Comment: Thanks, well that would suit me since I already subclassed the 2 bijectors I need to randomly parametrize. However, [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/TransformedDistribution) says nothing of `bijector_kwargs`, is `kwargs_split_fn` what you were suggesting? I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, admittedly this is pretty obscure functionality and ill-documented. kwargs_split_fn is the thing you want -- the idea is, some kwargs will go to the dist methods (sample, log_prob, etc) and some to the bij methods (forward, inverse_log_det_jacobian, etc). kwargs_split_fn says how to chop them up. by default, it expects (optional) dicts called distribution_kwargs and bijector_kwargs. this would mean you'd have to say `td.sample(bijector_kwargs={'a':1, 'b':2})` but you could get fancier with custom `kwargs_split_fn`. Feel free to email tfprobability@tensorflow.org for more discussion!